# Value of type void not allowed error in c++

Tags: c++

```
class Emp
{
    int no;
    char name[50];
public:
    void get_data();
} e;

void func_get();

enum ITEMTYPE
{
    MI_PARENT, MI_ACTION
};

struct MENUITEM {
    enum ITEMTYPE type;
    char *name;
    char *helpstring;
    void *p;
};

  // 1
struct MENUITEM get_data = {
    MI_ACTION,"Get","Enter to Get", e.get_data() }; // calling get_data() of type void by using abject e

// 2
struct MENUITEM root_draw = {
  MI_PARENT, "Options", "Enter to list the Options Menu", (void*)func_get /* calling   Global function which have return type void */
};
 struct MENUITEM *draw_list[] = {
  &get_data
 };
```

I am using above code in my program, when I am calling global function (case//2) 
the program is executing properly.But when I am trying to call function using object of   class(case //1) it shows error "Value of type void not allowed".
Can anyone tell me what is solution for this.I want to call my class function anyhow.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `e.get_data()` is a function **call**, `func_get` is a function.

Comment: ok..but if I want to call get_data(), how to do this.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense; `func_get` returns `void`; you cannot assign that to a `void *`.

Comment: What is the `void *p` member of `MENUITEM` supposed to *be*? Is it your intent that it be the result of a function *call*, or the address of a *function*? The answer to that will radically alter the answers you *get* from this admittedly obtuse question.

Answer (score 2):

I `suppose` the fourth member of `MENUITEM` is supposed to be a pointer to a callback function. `(void*)func_get` is the address of the function `func_get` cast to `void*`. Similarly, you can get the address of `&Emp::get_data`, but bare in mind the function belongs to the class, not the object, so you cannot say `&e.get_data`. Also, the function `get_data` being a non-static member of the class has a hidden parameter, that is pointer `this` (`Emp* this`). As a result, the signatures of `func_get` and `get_data` are not identical and calling `get_data` from outside the class through a function pointer should require you to pass the pointer to an object.

Answer (score 0):

Check syntax

```
(void*)func_get - this is not function call.
```